# Access Rails App Subdomains Through VirtualBox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, virtualbox

I'm running a Windows 7 VirtualBox on my Ubuntu 13.10 machine where I have my rails app. I access my rails app through subdomains (i.e. subdomain1.lvh.me:3000) and I'm trying to access these same subdomains through my VB. I've read to change the host file but I haven't been able to make it work. Would I be using the Gateway IP or the IPv4 address?

The reason for me trying to accomplish this is to develop on my Ubuntu machine and test for IE issues on my VB without using paid third party websites to render my changes.

Answer (score 6):

I think that if, for example, your ubuntu machine's ip address is `192.168.0.123`, then it should suffice to have this line in your windows hosts file

```
192.168.0.123 subdomain1.lvh.me subdomain2.lvh.me subdomain3.lvh.me
```

Then on your windows vb you would access `subdomain1.lvh.me:3000` like you say.

Have you done this?  I don't know what you mean by " I've read to change the host file but I haven't been able to make it work. "  What isn't working?

Comment: Yes I tried this out with no success. What I mean by I haven't been able to make it work was that I can't access that subdomain from the windows machine. I've tried changing the network settings on my VB to Bridge Network as well but I still can't access the subdomains by doing subdomain1.lvh.me:3000

Comment: This worked for me in VMWare Fusion 7.1.1 with my Network Adapter set to Network Address Translation (NAT).

On OSX 10.10.1, I have Configure IPv4 set to "Using DHCP with manual address" and the IPv4 Address set to 10.0.0.5 (5 can be any unused value).

In hosts I have:
10.0.0.5 mysubdomain.lvh.me another.lvh.me

Comment: I don't see that setting anywhere in the latest Virtualbox, all I see is the ability to set the network adapter to NAT and that's it.